# UWP Windows Application Packaging Project in Visual Studio 15

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, desktop-bridge

I'm trying to use [Package desktop applications (Desktop Bridge)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-root) with UWP and WinFroms application. I'm following [UWP with Desktop Extension](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/) guide and have to add a “Windows Application Packaging Project” from “Windows Universal” category. I'm not sure if it is because I'm using Visual Studio 15, .NET Framework 4.5.2, Windows Application Packaging Project template is missed in installed UWP platform:

[image]

What I have tried is to install [Microsoft announces the Desktop to UWP Packaging Project for Visual Studio "15"](https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-announces-the-desktop-to-uwp-packaging-project-for-visual-studio-15/) which says *"Desktop to UWP Packaging Project for Visual Studio "15"."* but [Desktop Bridge Debugging Project](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.DesktoptoUWPPackagingProject) shows this message:

[image]

and log:

```
02.07.2019 14:43:50 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
02.07.2019 14:43:50 - -------------------------------------------
02.07.2019 14:43:50 - Initializing Install...
02.07.2019 14:43:50 - Extension Details...
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -   Identifier         : Centennial
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -   Name               : Desktop Bridge Debugging Project
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -   Author             : Microsoft
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -   Version            : 0.3.1
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -   Description        : A Project that enables a Classic Windows application to be debugged as a Universal Windows Platform application
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -   Locale             : en-US
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -   MoreInfoURL        : 
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -   InstalledByMSI     : False
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
02.07.2019 14:43:50 - 
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -   SignatureState     : ValidSignature
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -   SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -   Certificate Info   : 
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -       -------------------------------------------------------
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -       [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=MOPR, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -       [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -       [Serial Number] : ...
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -       [Not Before]    : 15.02.2017 23:10:16
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -       [Not After]     : 09.05.2018 23:10:16
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -       [Thumbprint]    : ...
02.07.2019 14:43:50 - 
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -   Supported Products : 
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -           Version : [15.0,)
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -           Version : [15.0,)
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -           Version : [15.0,)
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -           Version : [15.0,)
02.07.2019 14:43:50 - 
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -   References         : 
02.07.2019 14:43:50 - Signature Details...
02.07.2019 14:43:50 -   Extension is signed with a valid signature.
02.07.2019 14:43:50 - 
02.07.2019 14:43:50 - Searching for applicable products...
02.07.2019 14:43:50 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
02.07.2019 14:43:50 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Integrated)
02.07.2019 14:43:50 - Found installed product - Global Location
02.07.2019 14:43:50 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

[Package a .NET desktop application using the Desktop Bridge and Visual Studio Preview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/08/28/package-a-net-desktop-application-using-the-desktop-bridge-and-visual-studio-preview/) says *"the minimum version of the .NET Framework supported by the Desktop Bridge is 4.0, even if it’s highly recommended to target at least .NET 4.6.1."* I'm not sure, do I have just to change target to 4.6.1 or update VS15 to [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/)

Comment: This is VISX install error,  the better way is that update your Visual Studio or use Visual Studio 2019 latest version that contains Windows Application Packaging Project  template originally.

Comment: version 15 = VS2017, so it can't be used in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net), the Windows Application Packaging Project project is only available in Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio 2017 15.5 and later. The former is recommended. It's not supported in Visual Studio **20**15.

You should also make sure that your application to be packaged targets .NET Framework 4.6.2 or later. This is a [requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-prepare).